# When using Rembg in python to remove image background, how can I turn on the alpha matting?

Tags: python

[Here](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/danielgatis-rembg-python-imagery) is shown how to do it using curl.

Here is my code also from the same website:

```
from rembg.bg import remove
import numpy as np
import io
from PIL import Image

input_path = 'input.png'
output_path = 'out.png'

f = np.fromfile(input_path)
result = remove(f)
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(result)).convert("RGBA")
img.save(output_path)
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 3):

```
result = remove(
    f,
    alpha_matting=True,
    alpha_matting_foreground_threshold=240,
    alpha_matting_background_threshold=10,
    alpha_matting_erode_structure_size=10,
    alpha_matting_base_size=1000,
)
```